# Range Slider Help chakra React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, rangeslider

I need some assistance understanding the correct place to do my OnChange and Map in my JSON data into a Range Slider.
The component renders fine, I get the following error when I move the slider:

*Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')*

**Update:** CodeSanbox for reference, if there is a way to have a tooltip above the numbers that would be handy as well.
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ecstatic-sky-4dxd4x?file=%2Fcomponents%2FInfoCard.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A10%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A16%2C%22startColumn%22%3A10%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A16%7D%5D)

Code is as below:

```
  <RangeSlider
      colorScheme="red"
      onChange={(e) => {
        setFilter({
          ...filter,
          search: e.target.value,
        });
      }}
      aria-label={["min", "max"]}
      onChangeEnd={(val) => console.log(val)}
      defaultValue={[50, 100]}
      min={0}
      max={100000000000}
      step={10}
      {...info.map((item) => (
        <option value={item.price}>{item.price}</option>
      ))}
    >
      <RangeSliderTrack>
        <RangeSliderFilledTrack />
      </RangeSliderTrack>

      <RangeSliderThumb index={0} />
      <RangeSliderThumb index={1} />
    </RangeSlider>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Based on the live project it seems that the logic of the filtering was not matching the use of `RangeSlider`. This is a topic bigger than just the `RangeSlider` case, but here's my suggestions:

`RangeSlider` will provide an array of 2 numbers but the current filter logic seems to be based on (search?) string. You might want to rewrite it so that it filters any items out of the selected range (between the 2 numbers).

You can start by renaming your `filter` object something like `filterList` give it a few keys such as `name`, `priceRange`.

I also recommend having the item cards built visually for display first before working on the filters, so when you're figuring out the logic you can test with them easily.

**Configuring RangeSlider**

`e.target.value` will not capture the value here because for this component, the `onChange` gives a `number[]` array of numbers to the call back function.

According to the Chakra UI [document](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/range-slider/usage#getting-the-final-value-when-dragging-the-slider), for this case you might want to use `onChangeEnd` to get the final value of the range slider, instead of `onChange` which would trigger lots of updates.

Try this example to see if it solves the error:

```
<RangeSlider
  colorScheme="red"
  aria-label={["min", "max"]}

  // Set the event here
  onChangeEnd={(val) =>
    setFilter({
      ...filter,
      search: val,
    })
  }

  defaultValue={[50, 100]}
  min={0}
  max={100000000000}
  step={10}
>
  <RangeSliderTrack>
    <RangeSliderFilledTrack />
  </RangeSliderTrack>

  <RangeSliderThumb index={0} />
  <RangeSliderThumb index={1} />
</RangeSlider>
```

I removed this following code as the syntax has an error and it does not fit in the component. If this is the JSON data that needed to be mapped, would recommend do this in a separate component, and leave the ranger slider with a single purpose.

```
      {...info.map((item) => (
        <option value={item.price}>{item.price}</option>
      ))}
```

Comment: Thanks @John Li, Could you show me how you would map in the JSON data?

Comment: @Spatial_TX would have to see what data it is and how you would like it to display on the page and such. A live demo of the project would be a great help if it can be shared.

Comment: I have set up a codesandbox link. It has been added to the original question text.

Comment: @Spatial_TX Thanks I can see the sandbox, let me have a look.